# Why is "if (!(NULL != result))" better than "if (NULL == result)"

Tags: c, error-handling, null

The examples on the OpenSSL wiki (e.g. https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) often follow this pattern:

```
result = some_function_call();
if (!(NULL != result))
    handle_failure();
```

This "double negative" seems overly complicated and less readable than the following code:

```
result = some_function_call();
if (NULL == result)
    handle_failure();
```

Is there some reason why `!(NULL != result)` is "better" than `NULL == result`?

Comment: I don't see any reason, except maybe that there is some coding convention or standardization being used.

Comment: @Bruno Rijsman For me it looks like an obfuscated code.:)

Comment: Perhaps Openssl stuff is quite old style and that kind of negation is not readable. In general `if( result == NULL)` is more readable.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie *... maybe that there is some coding convention or standardization being used ...* That's not currently addressed in [the OpenSSL code standards](https://www.openssl.org/policies/codingstyle.txt). In fact, the opposite is implied - see the bottom,  Note the numerous deleted sections, however.

Comment: I would say it is poor style, needlessly obfuscated.  Sometimes, when I'm testing a more complicated condition, and especially If I'm doing error handling, I'll do the equivalent of `if(!(success)) { handle error; }` instead of `if(failure) { handle error; }`, because sometimes that ends up being significantly easier to read, but that definitely doesn't apply here.

Comment: No, double negatives are not more non-unclear.